# Replicate Keras tutorial without caching

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, caching

I am trying to replicate [this tutorial](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#an-endtoend-example-finetuning-an-image-classification-model-on-a-cats-vs-dogs-dataset) on the official Keras website. The tutorial is about transfer-learning and it is a guided example on how to use a pre-trained model on the famous *cats vs. dogs* dataset.

My question is related to the part where they do caching and adjust the buffer size which is carried out as follows:

```
batch_size = 32

train_ds = train_ds.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=10)
validation_ds = validation_ds.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=10)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=10)
```

If I skip this part, I am not able to replicate the tutorial anymore because I get an error where I fit the model. The error reads this:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_7: expected shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), found shape=(150, 150, 3)
```

### QUESTION

What modification do I need to implement to run the training without worrying about caching and related stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by skip? You need to batch your dataset even if you don't `cache()`.

Comment: I mean that I don't want to execute any of the code related to caching. That snippet changes something on the different datasets which I don't fully control. I wanna be able to train the model without applying any caching operation. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be? `cache()` operation is used for better performance while training. Applying `batch()` and `prefetch()` should be enough for your case.

Comment: I am not sure I explained my point correctly. I do not want to apply any of those. So no `batch()` and no `prefetch()`. Is this possible? And if so, how would I change the code to make it work correctly? Thx

Comment: Pretty much all Keras models/layers require a batch dimension. It doesn't really make sense to not "want" those things, and it is completely independent of caching. If you want to pass single inputs, you can use `batch(1)` to add a batch dimension of size 1.

Comment: You may omit `prefetch()` but you need `batch()` if you will use tf.data API.

Comment: I indeed removed both `cache()` and `prefect()`. I can give you the answer right if you formally write a solution. Thanks! '

Answer (score 0):

To remove the caching and prefetching (which uses a caching mechanism) from this code, simply remove those methods from the input pipeline, as follows:

```
batch_size = 32

train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)
validation_ds = validation_ds.batch(batch_size)
test_ds = test_ds.batch(batch_size)
```

The remaining code from the tutorial will then work as normal, except the dataset won't use caching.

As others have pointed out, the `.batch()` method is independent of caching, but is required to arrange the dataset into batches which are fed to the model sequentially. When you skipped this entire code block, the error you received was to do with the `.batch()` method being skipped.

`.batch()` adds an outer dimension to the dataset, which the standard keras models and layers (like the ones used in that tutorial) expect as input. This is why you got the error "Expected shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), found shape=(150, 150, 3)".

You can read more information about the chaining of methods [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#basic_mechanics), about batching and the `.batch()` method [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#batching_dataset_elements), the `.cache()` method [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache) and the `.prefetch()` method [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch).